# Профиль пользователя в Django

Tags: python, django, users, profile

Попытался расширить профиль пользователя новыми полями, но вконец запутался. Итак, стандартно у меня есть модель профиля.

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    decsription = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Описание", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Простая форма:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ['decsription']
```

А теперь путаница с урлами и функциями. Нужно добавить ссылку на профиль на главной странице, а также возможность редактирования своих данных. Пробовал делать через DetailView и UpdateView, но с профилями так это не работает. 
Профиль вызвался по простой функции из мануала:

```
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

а в темплеите

```
<a href="{% url 'app_cabinet:view_profile' %}"> Личный кабинет: {{ user.username }} </a>
```

Но тут беда, не видны новые поля из Profile. С редактированием вообще не справился.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что не видны новые поля?

Comment: по тому, что даже в админке не появились новые поля у пользователя

Comment: Ну да, вы ж не добавляли поля для модели User, а создали новую модель Profile — вот админку модели Profile и смотрите

Comment: ой, да, прошу прощения за тупость)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендую Вам связать их, а редактировать профиль через основную модель пользователя. Реализовать подобный функционал можно через сигналы в Django

*Пример:*

***models.py:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_or_create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        try:
            instance.profile.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Если экземпляр пользователя только был создан - создаётся профайл. Если же он по какой-то причине отсутствует - аналогично. В иных случаях данные сохраняются.

Теперь можно редактировать профиль так:

```py
user.profile.decsription = "Некоторое описание"
user.save()
```

К полям из профайла можете обращаться так:

```py
user.profile.decsription
```

Comment: спасибо, работает! как можно добавить кнопку "редактировать" на страницу профиля для изменения значений полей?

Comment: Второй вариант решения задачи через сигналы и AppConfig. Подсмотрел, сделал, получилось, но пока ничего не понял в этой теме.