# Как лучше расширить модель User в Django?

Tags: python, django

Я хочу сделать своего юзера, добавив ему дополнительных полей. Могу ли я сделать вот так:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()

class Client(User):
    my_custom_field = models.DateField()
```

Если могу, то чем этот подход хуже, чем наследование от `AbstractUser`? Какие минусы и подводные камни?

Comment: Я бы просто создал отдельную модель и связал её отношением `OneToOne`. [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992547/339283)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Ну в принципе так даже проще, не придется менять в настройках AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: просто оставлю это здесь :) https://habr.com/ru/post/313764/

Comment: @ZaArs О, это хорошая статья, спасибо)