# Как заполнить поля кастомной модели django при регистрации пользователя

Tags: django

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = Person.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'balance':user.money})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Когда я регистрирую юзера и вхожу в аккаунт, мне вылезает ошибка, мол не Person не найден.Как можно заполнить поле модели при регистрации? Гугл не помог

Comment: Посмотрите [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992552/339283), возможно это поможет Вам.

Comment: Должно работать проще user.person -> это и есть искомый Person

Answer (score 0):

Можно создавать объект Person при регистрации, или использовать get_or_create при создании пользователя.

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:    
         user = Person.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
         return render(request, 'index.html', {'balance':user.money})
    else:
         return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Так же стоит установить стандартное значение для поля баланса, чтобы у новых пользователей он сразу был равен 0

```
balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Только что зареганые пользователи отсутствуют в полях модельки Person.Как их туда добавить?

Comment: @DaybNs get_or_create в этом случае создаст модельку Person со связью на модельку User

Comment: Я это уже понял, но все равно у меня ничего не происходит.Миграции применял.Не знаю в чем дело

Comment: При регистрации создается профиль, но поля моей модельки не заполняются.

Comment: А еще, используя ваш код, я получаю трейсбек:
UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
Связан с ээтой строкой:user = Person.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

Comment: @DaybNs вы не поняли, что юзер для фильтрации это request.user?

Окей, будет вот так user = Person.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)